# Function problems

Tags: functions

Find all functions of the form
$$f(x)=\frac{b}{cx+1}$$
where $b$ and $c$ are integers, and for all real numbers x such that $f(f(f(x)))$ is defined the following equation holds:
$$f(f(f(x)))=x$$

I'm not really sure how to go about this question, only that $f(x)=1/x$, and that $f(f(x))$=$\frac{b}{c\frac{b}{cx+1}+1}$ will most likely be used. Any solutions or tips to point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ' f(x)=1/x ' I don't get that part ?

Comment: what kind of term have you got?

Comment: I just mean that it's a simplified version of f(f(f(x)))=x

Answer (score 1):

HINT: after substitution three times for $x$ the given term we get the equation
$$\frac{b (b c+c x+1)}{b c^2 x+2 b c+c x+1}=x$$
can you finish?

Comment: nope, can i can only make it into (bc+1)(cx^2+x-b)=0

Answer (score 0):

A dynamical approach:

Clearly, $b,c$ must both be non-zero. Then $f$ extends to a map of the real line union infinity.

As $f(\infty)=0$ and $f(0)=b$ a necessary condition is that $f(b)=\infty$ which implies $c=-1/b$. Then $f^3$ fixes the three points $0,b,\infty$. Any Möbius transformation fixing three point is the identity so the condition is also sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is **NO** function like that.

$f(0)=b$ and $f(b)=\frac{b}{bc+1}$, then

$$f(f(f(0)))=0\to f(f(b))=0\to f\left(\frac{b}{bc+1}\right)=0\to \frac{b}{\frac{bc}{bc+1}+1}=0\to\frac{b(bc+1)}{2bc+1}=0$$

that give us

$$b(bc+1)=0\to b=0 \text{ or }bc+1=0$$

If $b=0$ then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ what is not possible because $f(f(f(x)))=x$.

But $bc+1=0$ is also impossible because $f(b)$ will not be defined. Then there is no function like that.

Comment: @pok: Is it clear?

Comment: i dont see how f(f(f(0)))=0?

Comment: @pok: because $f(f(f(x)))=x$ for all real $x$, as is said.